# How to fix "Error: Watching remote files is not supported" problem in Visual Studio Code

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, visual-studio-code

I have Vue application that I don't run for a while and now I cannot start development server?! In meanwhile something updated and that don't work. I tried new clean vue/vuetify install and same problem!

Build for production works normally, only run development server don't work.

And important notice: when run "npm run serve" in command prompt (outside VS Code), it works normally. That not work only in VS Code Terminal. What is problem?

Node version is v10.16.0
Npm version is 6.10.3

VS Code About:

```
Commit: 036a6b1d3ac84e5ca96a17a44e63a87971f8fcc8
Date: 2019-08-08T02:33:50.993Z
Electron: 4.2.7
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763
```

Error (from terminal window):

```
> Executing task: npm run serve <


> portal@0.1.0 serve d:\Wamp64\www\portal
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
 10% building 2/2 modules 0 active ERROR  Error: Watching remote files is not supported.
Error: Watching remote files is not supported.
    at Server.setupWatchStaticFeature (d:\Wamp64\www\portal\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:405:13)
    at Object.watchContentBase (d:\Wamp64\www\portal\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:477:14)
    at forEach (d:\Wamp64\www\portal\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:550:24)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Server.setupFeatures (d:\Wamp64\www\portal\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:549:49)
    at new Server (d:\Wamp64\www\portal\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:125:10)
    at serve (d:\Wamp64\www\portal\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\serve.js:139:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portal@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portal@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sasa Gosovic\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-11T10_35_40_418Z-debug.log
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Press any key to close the terminal.
```

Comment: I have been refreshing this in the hopes that there will be a solution since the below by AdamDay did not work for me. However after and it may have been a bit of installing the webpack-dev-server and vue-cli-service but even after that I got the error until I created vue.config.js and add 
`module.exports = {
    lintOnSave: false,
    devServer: {
        contentBase:'public',
        port: 9000
      }
  }` 
because by the looks of it dev-server did not know where to watch. I will still be looking for a proper answer. Thank you for asking the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly the same issue here. I resolved it by rolling back the version of webpack-dev-server.

```
npm install webpack-dev-server@3.7.2 --save-dev
```

Looks like the setupWatchStaticFeature function has changed between 3.7.2 and 3.8.0 which is triggering the issue.

Comment: Thanks. It solves the problem. Still I am worried about how to avoid things like this. The average javascript project has over 100 modules, so how do I know if something goes wrong after an update??

Answer (score 1):

You can eddit the `vue.config.js` file, adding following code:

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: './public'
}
```

More details: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2190#issuecomment-520670599

Answer (score 0):

Until the [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2190#issuecomment-520670599) is open, a workaround could be to use Git Bash instead of Windows command line to run `npm run serve`. I modified `Server.js` to output the `contentBase` variable. When using Windows command line or Vue UI, the variable contained "c:\...". Using Git Bash on my Windows 10 machine it contains "C:\..." and it worked.